# Angular translate variable replacement

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

I would like to use a variable in my translation but I don't know how to do it in my template.

In my HTML template :

```
 <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <md-autocomplete md-no-cache="vm.noCache" 
                                    md-search-text="user.searchUser" 
                                    md-items="userItem in vm.querySearch(user.searchUser)" 
                                    md-item-text="userItem.display"
                                    md-selected-item-change="vm.selectedItemChange(userItem, user)"
                                    md-min-length="0"
                                    required>
                    <md-item-template>
                        <span md-highlight-text="user.searchUser" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{userItem.display}}</span>
                    </md-item-template>
                    <md-not-found>
                        {{ 'user.autocomplete.no_user' | translate:'{ username: user.searchUser }' }}

                    </md-not-found>
                </md-autocomplete>
            </md-input-container>
```

and my translation file (json) :

```
"user": {
            "autocomplete": {
        "no_user" : "No user has been found ({{username}})",
     }
}
```

How can I use user.searchUser to show that message ?

Thank very much !

Comment: What is displayed in the view with your current code ?

Comment: This : "No user has been found ()" username variable seems to be ignored

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here the answer to do it directly in the HTML template :

```
{{ 'user.autocomplete.no_user' | translate:{ username: user.searchUser } }}
```

Comment: Note that it is important the blank between the end of translation parameters and the interpolation bindings. Removing it (`{{ 'user.autocomplete.no_user' | translate:{ username: user.searchUser }}}`) will throw a 'Unexpected end of expression' error

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object containing all your translation parameters and use it for the translation like this :

```
{{ 'user.autocomplete.no_user' | translate:translationParameters }}
```

Look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/86uWmmZAYxu9DNX7QwDB?p=preview) how I did it, for more details it's explain at the end of the section **Variable replacement in translate filter** of [Angular Translate doc](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I finally found how to do it directly in the template. I just had to remove the quotes : {{ 'user.autocomplete.no_user' | translate:{ username: user.searchUser } }}

Comment: @JoeAllen Ok, but I think it's almost the same solution, I just declare the object containing the translation parameters in the scope and you directly in the directive call. If your problem is solved if you could accept your answer or mine to close the question, it would be great ! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it in Angular 5+

translation file:

```
{
  "HELLO": "Hello {user}"
}
```

Template:

```
{ 'HELLO' | translate: { user: "World" } }
```

Displays: Hello World

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ELEMENT_TRANSLATE|translate}}

{{ 'ELEMENT_TRANSLATE'|translate:'{value: 111 }'}}

{{ 'ELEMENT_TRANSLATE'|translate:{value: user.searchUser} }}
```

The last one is the best one.